# isort a python directory manually and then can't push to remote repository

Tags: python, python-3.x, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit.com, isort

I am trying to add `isort`, `black` and `flake8` into my project's `pre-commit` hooks, it works fine when I edit one single file.

What I want to achieve is `isort` one directory of the project by `isort -rc .` and push the changes to remote repository but it gives me `Everything up-to-date` but when I check `git status` it shows me all modifications.

Can someone help figure out what I have done wrong? Below I post the screenshot and code snippets. Thanks!

[image]
 •100% ➜ git status
    On branch 2020-01-29-test-pre-commit
    Your branch is up to date with 'origin/2020-01-29-test-pre-commit'.

```
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    modified:   athlete_report/algorithm/yazs/cc_calculation_copy.py
    modified:   athlete_report/algorithm/yazs/dto/session_event.py
    modified:   athlete_report/algorithm/yazs/formula/flow_processor.py
    modified:   athlete_report/algorithm/yazs/input/flow_input_processor.py
    modified:   athlete_report/algorithm/yazs/input/single_source_handler.py
    modified:   athlete_report/algorithm/yazs/input/two_sources_handler.py
    modified:   athlete_report/algorithm/yazs/vertical_jump/vert_jump.py
    modified:   athlete_report/algorithm/yazs/yazs_calculation.py
    modified:   athlete_report/pdf_generator/athlete_report_builder.py

(mbp37)
src on  2020-01-29-test-pre-commit [+] via  mbp37
•100% ➜ git add .
(mbp37)
src on  2020-01-29-test-pre-commit [+] via  mbp37
•100% ➜ git commit -am "add modifications to athlete report"
seed isort known_third_party.............................................Passed
isort....................................................................Failed
- hook id: isort
- files were modified by this hook

Fixing /Users/hzhang/Work/yana-motion-lab/report-engine/src/athlete_report/pdf_generator/athlete_report_builder.py

black....................................................................Failed
- hook id: black
- files were modified by this hook

reformatted /Users/hzhang/Work/yana-motion-lab/report-engine/src/athlete_report/pdf_generator/athlete_report_builder.py
All done! ✨  ✨
1 file reformatted, 8 files left unchanged.

Flake8...................................................................Passed
(mbp37)
src on  2020-01-29-test-pre-commit [+] via  mbp37 took 3s
•100% ➜ git diff
(mbp37)
src on  2020-01-29-test-pre-commit [+] via  mbp37
•100% ➜ git push
Everything up-to-date
(mbp37)
src on  2020-01-29-test-pre-commit [+] via  mbp37 took 2s
•100% ➜ git diff
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because changes were made by `pre-commit` the commit was cancelled (as the contents were not correct to be committed)

You'll want to review the changes being made (`git status` / `git diff`) and if the automatic changes made by the tools look correct you'll then `git add -u` and re-run your `git commit` command (`^R` + `git commit` might be helpful here)

there's no commit to push because the commit was cancelled

Comment: `git diff` shows nothing and `git status` show the modified files

Comment: this likely means that isort is formatting in one way and then black is undoing that formatting -- there is an "black compatible" isort configuration that you'll want to use -- or you may want to use another import sorter -- for instance ([reorder-python-imports](https://github.com/asottile/reorder_python_imports) which is black compatible) (disclaimer: I'm the author of both pre-commit and reorder-python-imports)

Comment: Hey Anthony. I have added the black compatible isort configurations into my project. The issue occurs when I `isort -rc .` manually. in this case, what would be the best way to sort the imports for the whole existing project? Thanks!

Comment: [`pre-commit run --all-files`](https://pre-commit.com/#4-optional-run-against-all-the-files)

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day!

Comment: I have tried `pre-commit run --all-files`, everything looks fine, all of them show green pass but couldn't push to remote repo...

Comment: what does `git status` say? did you commit the changes?